# Merging multiple records into 1 record, group by field 'group'

Tags: qgis, merge, expression, aggregate, duplicates

I have a point geometry file (GeoPackage) which I am working with in QGIS. It contains tens of thousands of records which discuss the topic 'Mineral occurrences'. Within this point file exist thousands of records of duplicate data. The duplicates are grouped by field 'Group'.

I am trying to find a way to merge the duplicate records into one consolidated row using the 'Aggregate' function. The merging of the data must adhere to set rules. Please refer to the attached image:

1. Where field "Data_Ver" = 'Yes', then the "Name", "X", "Y", "Data_Ver" fields should be retained from this record, and not the other records.
2. When I have the majority of rows state the same value in the same field, then this value should be used.
3. When only one cell is populated with a value and rest (majority) are Null, then this populated value should be used (not the null value)
4. When all records are NULL, then obviously the answer is NULL
5. When you have varying values between the records, then all the data needs to be captured, by having an extra column titled "XXXXX_2", "XXXX_3.." and so on, to accommodate this extra data.

The idea behind this exercise is to ensure no additional data is lost when merging records.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: You could certainly create new attributes "comm_1, comm_2, comm_3..." and save the attributes from different rows into columns. But your use case is actually one-to-many relations. Read the documentation https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-one-or-many-to-many-relations.

Answer (score 1):

For this task, use [`Aggregate`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaggregate) algorithm. Under `Group by expression`, select your field `Group`. In the list below, you can decide for each attribute field in particular how it should be aggregated.

To keep the `X` and `Y` field for the feature with `Location_Verfied` = `'YES'`, edit the source expression for `X`and insert an expression instead:

```
case when "Location_Verfied" = 'YES' then "X" end
```

So for the feature where location is verfied, the expression returns the X coordinate value, for all other fields just `NULL`. Now set the Aggregate Function to `maximum` so that only the value containing the coordinate value will be kept.

Proceed accordingly for all other fields where you want to keep the value of the feature with location verified. You can create as many new fields as you want, based on existing fields or - as explained above - based on an expression.

*Screenshot, showing a simplified data structure that basically represents your use case:*
[image]

Comment: If I understood right, the other attributes than the coordinates should be kept also from the verified=false rows, perhaps as concatenated in this case.

Comment: Yes, I just showed it how to do for the coordinates field. For all other fields, proceed the same way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Did the answer solve your problem? You can use the same expression for the other fields, too, of course

Comment: Here in the comments it's difficult to format your text, so you should probably better open a new post and ask this as a separate question. As it is written, it's difficult to understand what you mean

Comment: Thank you Babel! I thought it might be a little hard to understand! I will make a new post and add the additional information. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So if this solution solves the initial problem, consider accepting it (hit the checkmark icon).

Comment: Hi Babel! I have updated the post to include more detail! I hope this is okay! Many thanks again!